# Using explode() on an Object

Tags: php

So I have an object. I take print_r() to it and get this:

```
QueryResult Object
(
[queryLocator] =>
[done] => 1
[records] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[Id] =>
[AdditionalReportEmails__c] => email@email.com, email@email2.com
[ShowReports__c] => 1
)
)
[size] => 1
[pointer] => 0
[sf:QueryResult:private] =>
)
```

I'm trying to explode the AdditionalReportEmails__c field along the comma delimiter. I'm just having trouble isolating that field from the rest. How can I pull solely that field from the object? Thanks!

Comment: Write a getter and explode the returned string? Or even better have the object do the exploding for you and obtain an array?

Comment: `explode(', ', $object->records[0]->AdditionalReportEmails__c)` work for you?